# Pc instanly booting into Manjaro without menu letting me choose which OS

Tags: dual-boot, manjaro

I recently switch to Linux(Manjaro) to try the Os. I have a windows 7 and Manjaro, I used this for a few days. Today I turned on the Pc and it instanly booted to Manjaro so I was shocked cuz all my documents and my my work is all gone! Someone please help me.

Comment: During boot: press and hold shift. It should get you into the boot menu. I assume `grub` is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you did a full wipe of your hard drive when you installed Manjaro all of your files should still be there. If you have grub boot loader installed, press and hold the shift key like FelixJN said above. If that doesn't work repeatedly press probably the F12 key (it might be different for you computer) AS SOON as your press the power button to do a one-time boot. It should bring you to a screen that shows all of your installed operating systems (Manjaro, Windows 7, etc.). There you can you the arrow keys to select one and then press enter.